# JavaScript GoogleMaps move placemarker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the following JavaScript to load GoogleMaps and center on London.  The user can then move the map and place a marker for which I save the longitude and latitude.  The code works fine for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 51.5073509, lng: -0.12775829999998223};

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng),
            zoom: 13
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));

            var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                draggable: true,
                map: map,
                anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(myLatLng)
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseup", function(event) {
                $('#id_latitude').val(this.position.lat());
                $('#id_longitude').val(this.position.lng());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                infowindow.close();
                marker.setVisible(false);
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    return;
                }

                // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);
                }
                marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
                }));
                marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                marker.setVisible(true);

                $('#id_latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                $('#id_longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());

                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [
                    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');
                }

                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        if ($('#map-canvas').length != 0) {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        }

    });
```

I want to amend the code so that when I reload the user's information it automatically goes to the marker they set and they can move it to another location.  I cannot work out how to do this.  Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "reload the user's information"? is that doing an ajax call or something else?

Comment: I'm using Python with the Django framework.  This gets called using a Django form and I hold the latitude and longitude of the previous marker.  I want to take that data and center the map on the marker (which I can do) and be able to move the marker (which I can't).  So given inputs of myLat and myLon how do I bring up the marker and make it so I can move it to a different position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for changing the marker's position, you should keep the marker object as a global variable after you create it so that you could edit it somewhere else outside the `initialize` function.

And after you have reload the user's information, you can change the position of the marker this way:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.397, 140.644);  // new latlng here.
marker.setPosition(latlng);    // marker is what you keeped global.
```

I don't know anything about the Django framework, if it supports callbacks or something like this, do the change work there.

```js
var markerGlobal;

function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  markerGlobal = marker;
}

function changeMarkerPosition() {
  var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.397, 131.084);
  markerGlobal.setPosition(newLatlng);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="changeMarkerPosition()">Click me!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is then just hiding my place field and not showing the marker

Comment: @HenryM I have add a code snippet that works. check for it. Maybe if the new position is out of zoom, you should call the setCenter additional.

Comment: I cannot move the marker on this code snippet.  The marker stays in the same location and the map moves.

Comment: @HenryM check again. I have add the marker's draggable feature for you have got done with it according to your code posted.